# Return value of background process

Tags: unix, shell, background, return-value

I need to take some action based on the return value of a background process ie if it terminates in the first place.

Specifically : in ideal operation, the server which I run as the background process will just keep running forever. In such cases keeping it in the background makes sense, since I want my shell script to do other things after spawning the server. But if the server terminates abnormally, I want to preferably use the exit return value from the server to decide whether to kill my main script or not. If that's not possible I at least want to abort the main script rather than run it with a failed server.

I am looking for something in the nature of an asynchronous callback for shell scripts. One solution is to spawn a monitoring process that periodically checks if the server has failed or not. Preferably I would want to do it without that within the main shell script itself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could nest the background process inside a script. For example, if the process you wish to send to the background is called foo:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo

if [ $? ]
then 
    # do something here if process failed
fi
```

Then just run the above script in the background instead of `foo`. you can kill it if you need to shut it down, but otherwise it will never terminate as long as `foo` continues to run, and if foo dies, you can do whatever you want to based on its error code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use shell traps to invoke a function when a child exits by trapping SIGCHLD.  If there is only one background process running, then you can `wait` for it in the sigchld handler and get the status there.  If there are multiple background children running it gets a little more complex;  here is a code sample (only tested with bash):

```
set -m # enable job control
prtchld() {  
  joblist=$(jobs -l | tr "\n" "^")
  while read -a jl -d "^"; do
    if [ ${jl[2]} == "Exit" ] ; then 
      job=${jl[1]} 
      status=${jl[3]}  
      task=${jl[*]:4}
      break  
    fi  
  done <<< $joblist
  wait $job 
  echo job $task exited: $status
}
trap prtchld SIGCHLD

(sleep 5 ; exit 5) &
(sleep 1 ; exit 7) &

echo stuff is running

wait
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the first one better for my purpose, I presume in the "do something here if process failed" I can kill the script that called this wrapper script for foo by using it's name.

I think the first solution works well for multiple children. Anyway, I had to get this done quickly, so I used a hack which works for my application:

I start the process in background as usual within the main script, then use $! to get it's pid ( since $! returns last bg pid), sleep for 2 seconds and do a ps -e | grep pid to check if the process is still around based on the return value of (ps -e | grep pid). This works well for me because if my background process aborts it does so immediately ( because the address is in use).