# Issue unable to execute all bash script within bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, multiprocess

I have following bash script which runs two process in parallel (two bash scripts internally), I need two bash scripts two run in parallel once both are finished I need total time execution. But the issue is the first bash script ./cloud.sh doesn't run but when I run it individually it runs successfully, and I am running main test bash script with sudo rights.

Test

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s%3N)
./cloud.sh &
./client.sh &
end=$(date +%s%3N)
echo "Time: $((duration=end-start))ms."
```

Client.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker build -t testing .'
```

Cloud.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s%3N)
ssh kmaster@192.168.101.238 'docker build -t testing .'
end=$(date +%s%3N)
echo "cloud: $((duration=end-start)) ms"
```

Comment: take a look here for what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736060/return-value-of-background-process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A background process won't be able to get keyboard input from you. As soon as it tries so, it will receive a `SIGTTIN` signal which will stop it (until it is brought back to the foreground).

I suspect that one or both of your scripts asks you to enter something, typically a password.

Solution 1: configure sudo and ssh in order to make them password-less. With ssh this is easy (ssh key), with sudo this is a security risk. If `docker build` needs you to enter something, you are doomed.

Solution 2: make only the ssh script (`Cloud.sh`) password-less and keep the sudo script (`Client.sh`) in foreground. Here again, if the remote `docker build` needs you to enter something, this won't work.

How to wait for your background processes? Just use the `wait` builtin (`help wait`).

An example with solution 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s%3N)
./cloud.sh &
./client.sh
wait
end=$(date +%s%3N)
echo "Time: $((duration=end-start))ms."
```